# How can I free up storage on my SGS II?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, storage, ram

I got a notification on my SGS2 today that said the phone memory is nearly full.

So my question is: How can I move apps to the internal USB storage? I don't have a micro SD card in my phone.

Comment: I'd probably start by going into manage applications and sort by size, then clear the data on some of the larger ones.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can move apps to the "internal SD card" by going to `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications`, selecting individual apps, and choosing "Move to SD" if it's supported. Though honestly I keep all my apps off the SD, so I don't know whether it tries to move them to external or internal SD.

Comment: hi i follow your steps but when i try "Move to SD Card" buttom i get Failed to move application: not enough memory, and yes i have 4gb free space

so can you tell where is the problem?

Comment: @Hussainoo `Settings -> SD card and phone storage` should list a couple storage areas with their names, size, and free and used space.  Could you post those numbers or a screenshot?

Comment: Device memory 1.8GB used / 280Mb Free ---- SD Card 7.5gb used / 4.0GB FREE

Comment: @Hussainoo Hmm, that's quite strange.  The good news is, 280 MB should last you a while.  Hopefully someone else with an SGSII has encountered this and can help.

Answer (score 1):

Check the space used up by your text messages, which is stored in internal storage. Whenever I receive the "memory full" notification, I delete all text message threads, and that always fixes the problem, especially if it's been months and I've received pictures, etc. I also use [SMS Backup +](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync) to backup all of my text messages in my Gmail before deleting all of my text messages.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the actual internal storage is full on the SGS II. It's probably the data or cache partitions that are full.

You can go in to the `settings -> applications -> manage applications` and clear the cache/data for the "high use" apps.

I have a lot of apps installed but still have tons of "internal storage" space left, but I only have 11% (19.3M) left in my /datadata partition. it was at about 2MB the other day, but I removed a lot of apps that I don't really ever use anymore.

My /data partition, where the applications are installed, has a max size of 1.8GB, but my cache partition, where temporary data is stored, only has 80MB. The cache could fill up quickly if you use apps that cache a lot of data.

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution to this problem. On the SGS2, the Move to SD button actually moves the apps to the external SD (/mnt/sdcard/external_sd) and NOT the interal USB (/mnt/sdcard). This means that the application's data is still on internal USB, but the application itself gets moved to external SD.

The only solution to install large applications on the internal storage is to repartition the 16GB so that you have a much bigger phone partition and smaller internal USB partition (they are both partitions of the same physical disk).

Comment: How can I repartition ?

Comment: Use fdisk or parted from the recovery terminal. If done incorrectly your phone can be permanently bricked. You can increase the size of the /data partition to 13.5GiB and reduce the /sdcard partition to around 512MB and delete the /preload partition.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue and the below link helped :)

http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s-ii/272384-galaxy-s2-cannot-download-updates-new-apps.html

This works!!

Comment: What works? The link? Good. Because as soon as it dies, your answer stops working ;) Which is why we prefer to have at least an abstract included of what the page behind the link describes, so the idea would survice. Do you mind to [edit] your answer and include that abstract? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The thread in linked page has 112 replied (at the moment). Please copy the reply(ies) that helped you here. Until then this answers is very low quality.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following:

1) Dial `*#9900#` and tap the second instruction (Delete dumpstate/logcat). This procedure freed about 400MB of my (internal) phone storage.

2) Or check out this link for lasting solution: http://techotv.com/samsung-galaxy-s2-internal-storage-apps-space-tutorial/

I hope you will find these very helpful.