# Galaxy S2 device memory filled

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, internal-storage

I have a Galaxy S2 (4.1.2), with 2 GB for app storage, and 16 GB of storage. I have no external SD card and no desire to buy one.

The 2 GB app storage is now almost filled, and I can't find a way to move apps to the 16GB internal storage. My internal storage is almost empty, but I simply can't utilize it. The move app to SD option does not work because the internal storage is not recognized as SD.

How can I deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an unresolvable issue but you can find more info at the link below

https://android.stackexchange.com/a/12108/57153

Answer (score 1):

Type in keypad *#9900# option 2 delete dumpstate logcat it really works and gets rid of that annoying disk thing at top of notifications and can download again
Hope it helps. I had the same issue and this worked.